# FileNameFinder().getFileNames fails on one Jenkins node

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Getting a list of files from jenkins workspace using groovy fails on one node but it works on another. 
Here is the code in the pipeline:

```
 def pd = pwd()
 bat "dir $pd"
 def bat_files = new FileNameFinder().getFileNames(pd, 'G*.bat')
```

Output:

```
C:\Jenkins\Slave\workspace\TestFolder\CodeTestPipe>dir C:\Jenkins\Slave\workspace\TestFolder\CodeTestPipe 
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is AAA1-73FA

 Directory of C:\Jenkins\Slave\workspace\TestFolder\CodeTestPipe

01/23/2017  05:34 PM    <DIR>          .
01/23/2017  05:34 PM    <DIR>          ..
01/23/2017  05:34 PM                 4 GOL.bat
               1 File(s)              4 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  134,906,617,856 bytes free
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
C:\Jenkins\Slave\workspace\TestFolder\CodeTestPipe does not exist.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.types.AbstractFileSet.getDirectoryScanner(AbstractFileSet.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.FileIterator.setNextObject(FileIterator.java:119)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.FileIterator.hasNext(FileIterator.java:81)
    at groovy.util.FileNameFinder.getFileNames(FileNameFinder.groovy:44)
    at groovy.util.FileNameFinder$getFileNames.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.util.FileNameFinder.getFileNames(FileNameFinder.groovy:31)
    at
```

Comment: Are the files really existing on the node where the failure happens? Projects only get checked out from scm on one node (meaning the other nodes do not have those checked out files), but you could share the resources between nodes via [stash/unstash](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#unstash-restore-files-previously-stashed).

Comment: I am not using scm. As you can see the 'dir' command works on the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipelines are executed on the Jenkins master, and only through the magic of remoting-enabled APIs do things happen on the selected node. So File, and everything using File, doesn't work, and never will: It always executes on master.

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/yBiYbwWjg-I

I was able to get the files by using the dir in bat command:

```
def bat_out = bat( returnStdout: true, script: '@echo off & dir /b G*.bat').trim()
```

Comment: Just use the pipeline command `findFiles`. See https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#findfiles-find-files-in-the-workspace