# check existence of a set of files in Groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have written a Groovy script to check the existence of a file `field1_field2_field3.txt` in my unix path.

```
def fileName = "/path/to/file/field1_field2_field3.txt"
File f = new File(fileName);
if(f.exists()) 
{ 
   println (" Required files exists.. \n");
}
```

Now i want to extend this script to check if the files with name `field1_field2_*.txt` exist.

Kindly let me know if there is a command which can give me the desired list of files or i should look to implement using regular expressions.

Comment: You can't do this with Jenkins Pipelines Groovy (only works under a few small circumstances). Can you provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: First you say "check if files with the name exists" and then it turns into "give the list of files". Which one are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I originally suggested using FileNameFinder, but it seems that's not allowed, and for good reason.  Groovy scripts are run on the master, so file finds wouldn't happen on the slave where the code is anyway.

You'll probably have to do something along the lines of this:
[FileNameFinder().getFileNames fails on one Jenkins node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833308/filenamefinder-getfilenames-fails-on-one-jenkins-node)

Perhaps:

```
def filesListAsString = bat( returnStdout: true, script: '@echo off & dir /b /path/to/file/field1_field2*.txt').trim()
```

Which should give you a whitespace-delimited String listing of files that match.

Comment: I got following error with suggested code: `Scripts not permitted to use new groovy.util.FileNameFinder`